# How to construct a PDA for n(a) is less than or equal to 2n(b)

Tags: automata, computation-theory

So here is where I am stuck, I have to construct a PDA that would accept words from  {a,b}* with the condition n(a) is less than or equal to 2n(b)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Answer (score 0):

Put yourself into the frame of mind of a pushdown automaton. All you know how to do is read input and the stack, and then push/pop and change state based on what you see. If you start reading a string and need to tell whether it's in the language, what can you do?

It seems to me the best we can do starting out is to remember how many `a`s we are reading. Until we see `b`s, there's no reason to do anything else. That is, simply read `a`s and push them on the stack. The following rules should suffice:

```
Q    i    s    Q'    s'
--   --   --   --    --
q0   a    Z    q0    aZ
q0   a    a    q0    aa
```

Now, what happens when we see a `b`? If we want at least twice as many `b`s as `a`s, we can't just cross of `a`s for each `b`, since that would give at least as many `b`s as `a`s but not at least twice as many.

What if we cross off two `a`s for each `b`? Well, that gives us at least half as many `b`s as `a`s, which is the wrong direction. This suggests crossing off one `a` for every two `b`s, which turns out to be correct. The rules:

```
Q    i    s    Q'    s'
--   --   --   --    --
q0   b    a    q1    a
q1   b    a    q2    -
q2   b    a    q1    a
```

Note we created a new state `q2` which has one rule in common with `q0` but not the ones for reading `a`s. Indeed, once we start reading `b`s, we don't want to allow any more `a`s to be read. Leaving out the rules will crash the automaton and reject the string.

If we have exactly twice as many `b`s as `a`s, we will end up in state `q2` with no more input and an empty stack. If we have additional `b`s, we need a rule to allow them. It suffices to add a self loop on state q2:

```
Q    i    s    Q'    s'
--   --   --   --    --
q2   b    Z    q2    Z
```

Taken together, these states and transitions should be pretty close to a working PDA for your language. Other options would have been to write a CFG first and then apply an algorithm to convert the CFG to a PDA, for example, a top-down or bottom-up parser.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about popping two bs per a but I didn't know how to write ID.